# What is the significance of designing the courtyard?

Tags: rituals, culture, festivals

I am not sure about North India, but in South India House wives draw a beautiful *Rangoli* (In south, *muggulu*)  in the courtyard (*angan*) of their house. Some women even use cow dung to design their courtyard.

[image]

<sub>Credit: blogspot.com</sub>

What is the significance of doing so? Are there any rituals to follow while designing the courtyard?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36870/rangoli-kolam-according-to-shastra-and-tradition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm adding the scriptural reference for "Rangoli" which is missing in the other answer.The answer is correct nonetheless.

Maharshi Veda Vyasa instructed as follows-

> Krutvaa **mandalakam** Braahme tooshneem evaakshataabhih pujayet satatam
>   yaa tu tasyaastupyanti Devataah, Yadgriham raajate nityam
>   mangalairanulepanaih, Tadgrihe vasate Lakshmeernityam
>   purnakalaanvitaa// Pativrataa tu yaa naari bhartru shushrushanotsukaa,
>   Natasya vidyate paapam ihaloke paratracha, Pativrataadharmarataa
>   Rudraanyeva na samshayah, Tasyaah paraabhavam kartum shaknoti najanah kashchit
>
> Meaning-**Devatas would be delighted to visit the houses where the home
>   fronts are decorated with ‘manadalaakaara’or auspicious designs of
>   varied colours at the Braahmi Muhurta time of early mornings even
>   without mantras!** Such home fronts appear that Devi Lakshmi along with
>   her companions has arrived in the house for good enlivening with
>   auspiciousness and brightness! A pativrata who sincerely serves her
>   husband shall qualify with attainment of her current and ensuing lives
>   and eventually attain the status of a Rudrani or Devi Parvati.

*Are there any rituals to follow while designing the courtyard?*

As said by Maharshi Vyasa, **no Mantras or rituals are required**.Only thing important is the time viz-the "Brahma Muhurta", when the Rangolis are to be drawn.

[image]

Source - [Dharma Bindu](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/Dharma%20Bindu.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

According to popular belief, Rangolis are drawn to welcome the Gods into the house.

I have not heard of the courtyard being designed with cow dung, but it is cleaned with cow dung. Early in the morning, women sweep the courtyard with cow dung, take a bath and then draw Rangoli.

A story I have heard (I have no reference) is that the Rangolis, usually designed using rice flour, attract sparrows and is food for them.

In South India, Rangolis are drawn every single day, though not as elaborate as the ones drawn during festivals. The swastika, Goddess Lakshmi and star designs are the most common. Women are hired solely to sweep the courtyard and draw Rangoli every day.

Reference: Seen it done every morning

Comment: Love your reference :-)

Comment: During Sankranti festival cow dung is used for decoration [see here](http://imgur.com/a/bUSfG), at the middle of Rangoli it is placed. But I don't know the reason. I guess it is just a tradition. BTW +1 for your reference :)