# Rangoli (Kolam) according to shastra and tradition

Tags: culture, tradition

What powder is the ideal to put rangoli?

Is current rangoli colors are tradition? If not what is natural and tradition substitute for colors?

Which location is the ideal to put rangoli? In front of altar? In front of courtyard? Or in front of Tulasi? Or anywhere we like?

Are there any restriction on symbols which we use in front of home because outside home mean anyone may step on it?

Are peacock, dolls etc rangoli designs tradition and according to shastra?

Are there any shastra references on these information?

Also any shastra references on what type of rangoli designs are ideal?

Comment: Related - [What is the significance of designing the courtyard?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3551/5212)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Fom Haribhakti Vilasa]

This is one reference so far I got and will update soon from Haribhakti Vilasa.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Purana It is stated "One should joyfully cleanse and decorate the temple of Vishnu by drawing various mandalas like padmas and swastikas with different attractive colors."

From Hari Bhakti Vilasa

White color from rice or barley, yellow from tumeric, red from kum kum, black from barley burn and collected Ash, green color by mixing barley black ash and red Kum Kum.